# Google Cloud Speech to text api not returning timestamps in batchRecognize method

Tags: gcloud, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am using the node library of @google-cloud/speech. When I use the V1 version, the results look fine with the transcript and timestamp of each sentence in transcript but when I use v2 version, I only get the transcript without the timestamps. Am I missing something?

```
const transcriptionRequest = {
            recognizer: recognizerName, 
            config: {
                // Automatically detects audio encoding
                autoDecodingConfig: {},
                model: 'latest_long'
            },
            // content: content,
            // uri: gcsUri,
            files: [{ uri: gcsUri }],
            recognitionOutputConfig: {
                gcsOutputConfig: {
                  'uri': 'gs://abc.com/episodesAudio/TerryMoore_2023_VO_Intro_latest_long2_v22/'
                }
            },
            processingStrategy: {}
        };

        const response = await client.batchRecognize(transcriptionRequest);
```